# PHP Array with Select List

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to print flags beside country names, so how can i loop through option tag using arrays.

Example :

```
$newarray = array("USA"=>"flag/usa.png", "UK"=>"flag/uk.png");

<select name ="options"> 
<option value="US">USA</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
</select>
```

I can access this array using `$newarray['USA']`;

but i want the flag icon printed beside the country name whenever a user select the country in the option tag.

Comment: This is nothing you can do with server side logic. You need some additional client side logic for this, so javascript.

Comment: You can use Ajax and return result from array_search

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve it :

```
$newarray = array("USA"=>"flag/usa.png", "UK"=>"flag/uk.png");

echo '<select name ="options"> ';
foreach($newarray as $n=> $nv)
{
  echo '<option value='.$n.' style="background-image:url(https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-square-grunge-sign-260nw-1474408826.jpg);">'.$n.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Just replace url with $nv variable

Comment: This will show the flag for every option though. Not exactly what OP was asking

Comment: I want to show for every option, like there are 200+ countries in the option tag, lets say user has selected USA then i want something like [flagicon] [countryname] something like that

Comment: @MohammadSameer Try implementing it once it will give u same output or you want to display image only when it is selected?

Comment: some info : 

I have the country drop down menu in a separate page i.e., submit.php whenever a user submit a forms with details like name, country, gender, bio it gets submitted on index.php so these are on two separate pages, the script i'm using uses PDO and access details like name, gender etc from MYSQL database table using $user['name'], $user['gender'] like that.

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy to loop through that array and display the image, but you won’t be able to reliably display images inside a `<select>`. You could use a custom dropdown like the one from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#examples).

```
<?php

$countries = [
  'USA' => 'flag/usa.png',
  'UK' => 'flag/uk.png'
);

?>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" if="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Choose your country
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <?php foreach ($countries as $name => $image): ?>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <?php

        printf('<img src="%s" alt="" /> %s',
          htmlspecialchars($image),
          htmlspecialchars($name)
        );

        ?>
      </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get help of a designer for css related changes. You can change country icon on change of the drop down. This is simple solution using javascript. You can also use jquery and bootstrap for this type of requirement.

```
<?php
$array = array("USA"=>"flag/usa.png", "UK"=>"flag/uk.png");
?>

<div class="myclass">
    <h2>pick an option</h2>
    <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="javascript:goTo();">
        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
        <?php foreach ($array as $key=> $value){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value;?>"><?php echo $key;?></option>

        <?php }?>

    </select>
    <img id ="imgId" src="" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function goTo() {
        var location = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
        document.getElementById("imgId").src=location;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$country = array("USA"=>"flag/usa.png", "UK"=>"flag/uk.png");
?>
<img id ="CountryMap" src="" />
  <h2>Select Country and GET Map</h2>
    <select id="getMap"  onchange="GetMap();">
        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
        <?php foreach ($country as $key=> $value):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value;?>"><?php echo $key; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetMap() 
      {
        var location = document.getElementById("getMap").value;
        document.getElementById("CountryMap").src=location;
      }
</script>
```

Comment: This is rather a solution than an answer, you don't really explain how you solved it. For the one who asked: [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops over your array, repeating the same code for all entries of the array. It outputs a key and a value `($array as $key => $value)` where $key would be "USA" or "UK" and $value would be the flag.